# RabbitMQ River on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq

I have the rabbitmq river plugin installed for elastic search and am successfully able to queue messages via rabbitmq, but I don't know the next step. Am I supposed to be able to query the rabbitmq messages from elastic search? If so, what is the curl url for that?

Sorry, I am a newbie at rabbitmq and elastic search. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple kind of search:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?pretty
```

The new ElasticSearch guide is really good, check it out: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html